# vb.net tcp socket server has delay?

Tags: python, vb.net, sockets, delay

There are the socket server(VB.NET on windows 7) and the client(python on linux) apps.

The client sends data like below.
A, B, C, D, E

But server receives in very occasionally.
A, BCD, E

The delays happen.
(1 time per hours or few times per days)

The timing is very important for this app, so this problem has to be resolved.

And there is no internet connection and there is only direct LAN connection between the server and the client. There is no hub.
(I tried hub but the problem happened, too.)

Can I have to change the LAN card on the server to expensive one?
Currently, I'm using on-board LAN card. (Supermicro server type motherboard)

Or can I change some windows network properties?

Please advice.

Comment: This is normal behaviour for TCP - it's a byte/octet stream and cannot transfer messages longer than one byte.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the VB.Net code where this is occurring?